# Failed multi-region snapshots in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I'm unable to complete a multi-region(eu) snapshot for a particular disk in europe-west2. It takes over an hour to timeout and then returns an "Unknown Error". I have managed to snapshot this disk in a single region.

I've been able to get a multi-region snapshots working for other disks in the same region.

I've also tried various different options:

Stopped all services 
umounted the disk 
powered off vm

none of which seem to help. Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Comment: I have seen a few timeouts yesterday and today. However, I am not sure if it is my local Internet or an issue with Google Cloud. Enable the web browser debugger. Try again. You might see failing Javascript that can point to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue on Googles side, my snapshots eventually started to go through about 18 hours after the initial failure.